# What song is Obadiah playing on the piano?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, music-identification, iron-man-2008

At 57:50 in *Iron Man* (2008), Obadiah comes to visit Tony and is playing something on a piano. It sounds slightly classical. What piece is he playing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[IMDB Trivia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/trivia?item=tr0748697) states that:

> Obadiah Stane plays on the piano a musical piece written by eighteenth century composer Antonio Salieri. Salieri is best known as a jealous rival of Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, and was said to have murdered Mozart (although historical records have proven that, on the contrary, both had collaborated on, and promoted each other's work on several occasions). This serves as an appropriate parallel of Stark and Stane's relationship in the film.

With thanks to Eric Towers comment below, the piece is named "Concerto in Do Maggiroe Per Pianoforte eo Orchestra: Larghetto"

Comment: Can we know the name of the piece?

Comment: @FlaStorm32 : *Concerto in Do Maggiroe Per Pianoforte eo Orchestra: Larghetto*, from https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Antonio_Salieri

Comment: That IMDB quote has an unfortunate (and unnecessary) leap of logic embedded in it — there’s nothing about collaboration or cross-promotion that would prevent Mozart and Salieri from being rivals or Salieri from having killed Mozart. This would be easily fixed by eliding the phrase “on the contrary”. I made the edit, but it was rejected.

Comment: In English that'd be Concerto in C major for Piano and Orchestra (movement II, *Larghetto*).

Comment: @RLH the quote is implicitly comparing history to the movie Amadeus which in addition to the play it was inspired by - gave the public conciousness a Salieri that is fictional and slanderous.

Comment: @lucasbachmann No, the quote is saying that evidence that Mozart and Salieri collaborated and cross-promoted contradicts their being rivals and the possibility of Salieri murdering Mozart. It makes no reference to the movie Amadeus, and makes an unfounded and illogical inference. If the quote said that the rivalry and murder rumors (which predate Amadeus by over a century) are now believed to be false, that would be one thing. Saying that they are false based on Mozart and Salieri having at some times found their interests aligned is plain bad reasoning. …

Comment: … There’s a fundamental question here as to whether IMDB trivia is an authoritative enough source that it should be quoted as the basis for an answer (and then the specific question as to what to do when quoting the passage verbatim requires echoing faulty logic, hence my suggestion to elide the “on the contrary” connecting phrase and thus eliminate the fault in reasoning).

Comment: @RLH that's why I said "implicitly" and it is obviously contrasting history to the movie.  Why else would anyone be talking about Salieri?  "Best known" from what if not the movie and an earlier play.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Because rumors (and facts) about a Mozart/Salieri rivalry predate the movie by more than a century. (Even this discussion is a sidetrack from my main point, which is that the accepted answer relies on a quote that says “A is false because B” when B does not imply notA. It seems like we should at least not echo the logic-failure portion of the quote, either by eliding it or truncating the quote, and that it would be even better to use an actual authoritative source.)

Comment: A somewhat better source to quote on the song would be https://www.houstonpublicmedia.org/articles/arts-culture/2015/06/04/60791/7-classical-pieces-in-comic-book-movies/ (though it’s still a bit weasel-wordy); any necessary commentary on the truth of the rivalry could be quoted from something like https://www.theguardian.com/music/2003/dec/19/classicalmusicandopera.italy (or one of its sources).